# How can make ticket restriction in backoffice for different user-groups in Customer-Support perspective?

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, perspective, restriction, backoffice

OOTB in hybris there is three usergroups which use Customer-Support perspective in backoffce ( customersupportadministrationgroup, customersupportmanagergroup, customersuppotagentgroup ). How can make ticket restriction in backoffice for these different groups. I mean if I create ticket from storefront and these ticket is assigned to CustomerSupportAgent then if I login in backoffice as CustomerSupportAgent, I will see only ticket which are assigned to CustomerSupportAgent, on the other hand if I login with CustomerSupportManager I will see all tickets. It doesn't mean if ticket is assigned to CustomerSupportAgent or someone else. CustomerSupportManager will have access see all tickets, but CustomerSupportAgent will have access to see only ticket which are assigned to him. For this somewhere maybe should happen some flexiblesearch. Someone can help me?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at flexible search Search Restrictions - https://help.hybris.com/1811/hcd/8c428f8286691014970ceee87aa01605.html

```
INSERT_UPDATE SearchRestriction; code[unique=true]; principal(uid); query; restrictedType(code); active
; csAgentAssignedTicketsOnlyRestriction; csagentgroup; "{item:assignedAgent} = (?session.user)"; CsTicket; true
```